# MVC 4: Google Maps Autocomplete data not showing after input [Bootstrap]

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps, asp.net-mvc-4, autocomplete

I've seen to notice that using Google Maps Autocomplete doesn't really work as expected.  I had to do a few workarounds so that it can actually "appear".  Now the Autocomplete data is not showing after I start typing the city/country/region etc.

Here's my code.  It's REALLY frustrating. (I read about styling the .pac-container z-index to 10000 but that didn't work either.)

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: -33.8688,
      lng: 151.2195
    },
    zoom: 13
  });
  var input = /** @@type {!HTMLInputElement} */ (
    document.getElementById('pac-input'));

  var types = document.getElementById('type-selector');
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(types);

  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
  autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29)
  });

  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    infowindow.close();
    marker.setVisible(false);
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (!place.geometry) {
      window.alert("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
      return;
    }

    // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
      map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
    } else {
      map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
      map.setZoom(17); // Why 17? Because it looks good.
    }
    marker.setIcon( /** @@type {google.maps.Icon} */ ({
      url: place.icon,
      size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
      origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
      scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 35)
    }));
    marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
    marker.setVisible(true);

    var address = '';
    if (place.address_components) {
      address = [
        (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''), (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''), (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
      ].join(' ');
    }

    infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' + address);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });

  // Sets a listener on a radio button to change the filter type on Places
  // Autocomplete.
  function setupClickListener(id, types) {
    var radioButton = document.getElementById(id);
    radioButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
      autocomplete.setTypes(types);
    });
  }

  setupClickListener('changetype-all', []);
  setupClickListener('changetype-address', ['address']);
  setupClickListener('changetype-establishment', ['establishment']);
  setupClickListener('changetype-geocode', ['geocode']);
}
initMap();
```

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
.controls {
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 32px;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
#pac-input {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-left: 12px;
  padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 300px;
}
#pac-input:focus {
  border-color: #4d90fe;
}
.pac-container {
  font-family: Roboto;
  z-index: 0;
}
#type-selector {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4d90fe;
  padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
}
#type-selector label {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
</style>
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!--@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}-->

<div class="jumbotron">
  <h1>ASP.NET</h1>
  <p class="lead">ASP.NET is a free web framework for building great Web sites and Web applications using HTML, CSS and JavaScript.</p>
  <p><a href="http://asp.net" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more &raquo;</a>
  </p>
</div>

<div id="map" style="position: absolute; margin-top:10%; margin-left: 45%; width: 50%; height: 50%; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;"></div>

<input type="text" id="pac-input" class="controls" placeholder="Enter a location">
<div id="type-selector" class="controls">
  <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-all" checked="checked">
  <label for="changetype-all">All</label>

  <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-establishment">
  <label for="changetype-establishment">Establishments</label>

  <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-address">
  <label for="changetype-address">Addresses</label>

  <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-geocode">
  <label for="changetype-geocode">Geocodes</label>
</div>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&libraries=places"></script>
```

I found out that the problem is mainly Bootstrap.  I'm not sure how I can fix this issue.  I've seen examples of people trying to put that autocomplete thing on a bootstrap modal but that's not my goal.

Is there anyway to solve this?

P.S. Insert your API Key to see the results.

**UPDATE**
Now I believe it's Jquery because I deleted Bootstrap out of a vanilla project and it still doesn't work. I removed all jquery references and it worked but I don't understand.  You have to remove jquery in order to make the Google Maps Autocmplete work???

Comment: What exactly isn't working? The Places search results appear as expected in your example.

Comment: It does work in JSFiddle for some odd reason.  It does not work if you create a vanilla MVC project @vanburen

Answer (score 0):

I had almost the exact same problem (however I'm not using jQuery and I was using a key for the api) and finally found something that works. As such, I can't guarantee this will solve your problem but if you were struggling as much as I was, it's worth a shot.

1. Go to Google Console.
2. Create an api Key.
3. Enable "Google Maps Javascript Api" and add the 'key' parameter to your api url.
4. Enable "Google Places API Web Service".
5. Voila (hopefully).

Answer credit to [Hsuan-ming Yang](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38193790/4767608)